# Docker - Package not found even after source

Tags: ros, docker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to launch `rosbridge_server` inside docker.

This is my docker file:

```
FROM ros:noetic

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \ 
    ros-noetic-rosbridge-server \
    ros-noetic-gps-common


RUN apt-get update && \
    rosdep update 

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    lsof \
    python3-pip \
    ros-noetic-catkin 


ADD ./my_workspace /my_workspace

RUN /bin/bash -c 'source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash; \
        cd /my_workspace; catkin_make; \
        source /my_workspace/devel/setup.bash; \
        rospack find my_package'    #"rospack find" successfully prints my package's path. 
                                    #No problem here

#RUN rospack find my_package           #Here is the problem.
                                #If I uncomment this, I get an error that rospack is not found. 
                                       #It's like nor the source command or my package 
                                       #exist outside the previous RUN command

CMD ["./launch_ros_bridge.bash"] #Ros bridge is started but once 
                                 #I subscribe to a topic of my package,
                                 #it prints an error that "my_package" is not found
```

This is my `launch_ros_bridge.bash` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
roslaunch rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket.launch
```

The error I receive when `launch_ros_bridge.bash` is executed, is

> [-] [ERROR] [1624456872.953620]:
> [Client 0] advertise: Unable to import
> my_package.msg from package
> my_package. Caused by: No module named
> 'my_package'.
> [-] ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/noetic/share/ros
> [-] ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/noetic/share

Again, my package's path is not displayed.

My question is how can I successfully start and subscribe to `ros bridge server`  inside a docker?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/380937/docker---package-not-found-even-after-source/) by [Chris1343](https://answers.ros.org/users/72943/chris1343/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2021-06-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Add the `source /my_workspace/devel/setup.bash` into the `launch_ros_bridge.bash` script before running the roslaunch command.

Sourcing the `setup.bash` script will basically setup some environment variables in your bash instance so ROS can find all of your packages. In general, each `RUN` command is a basically a new bash instance where the environment variables from previous runs are not preserved. Your comment is actually correct in the fact that your source command does not really matter outside of the previous run command.

So like when opening a new terminal, you need to re-source the workspace for every one even if you source it in a previous one.

---

Originally posted by [404RobotNotFound](https://answers.ros.org/users/46260/404robotnotfound/) with karma: 331 on 2021-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-06-24**:
You don't need to `source` at all. Just prefix the command you want to run with `/my_workspace/devel/env.sh`. That will take care of setting everything up and run your command.

**Comment by [ruffsl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5234/ruffsl/) on 2021-07-06**:
As an example, you can also use the dot `.` directive in shell to source the ros envelopment without using bash: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/29c1af087afffb80ddc4ec172015fee2c8a37166/Dockerfile#L84